# Android NDK / JNI - undefined reference to function defined by using prebuild library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I tried to use a prebuild shared library in JNI.
But when I built JNI library, it always complain function undefined reference.

Here is my Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mtestlib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mtest/arm64-v8a/lib/libtest.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := mtest/arm64-v8a/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := mtest/arm64-v8a/lib/libtest.so
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := myJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myJNI.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/mtest/arm64-v8a/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := mtestlib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my JNI file.

```
#include "lucien_example_com_jtest_myNDK.h"
#include <android/log.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Mtest.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_lucien_example_com_jtest_myNDK_test
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring tmp){
    const char* str;
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(tmp,false);
    std::cout<< str << std::endl;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(tmp,str);
    mtest(str);
}
```

Mtest.h Header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cutils/properties.h>
#include <utils/Log.h>
int mtest(const char *str);
```

mtest source file:

```
#include "Mtest.h"
#define LOG_TAG "Test"
int mtest(const char *str){
    ALOGE("[Lucien] test(%s)", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I got complain undefined reference when JNI load mtest() function.
The header and prebuild lib are already included.
Which wrong step causes this error?
Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your function are not the same in .h file and source file:

```
int mtest(const char *str);

int mjpeg(const char *str){
    ALOGE("[Lucien] test(%s)", str);
    return 0;
}
```

try calling mtest in your source file:

```
int mtest(const char *str){
    ALOGE("[Lucien] test(%s)", str);
    return 0;
}
```

To match with your jni call:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_lucien_example_com_jtest_myNDK_test
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring tmp){
    ...
    mtest(str);
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Your jni function expect to return a jint but you aren't returning anything. Try with a return statement at the end of the function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_lucien_example_com_jtest_myNDK_test
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring tmp){
    const char* str;
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(tmp,false);
    std::cout<< str << std::endl;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(tmp,str);
    mtest(str);

    //Example:
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I paste the wrong source file.
In my source file, the function of header, source, and JNI call is matched.